# XCode UI Test long press and drag button left and right

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I have a button and like whatsapp mic button you can long press and move it left and right.

Now I need to write a test case for this button. What I have done so far is, I can drag to a particular location. Now i need to drag left and right but i cannot find any method to do it.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.buttons["Launch Chat"].tap()

app.tables.staticTexts["shivam"].tap()

let chatbarElement = app.otherElements["chatBar"]

let button = chatbarElement.children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 0)

let startPoint = button.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)) // center of element
var finishPoint = chatbarElement.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.7, dy: 0))

startPoint.press(forDuration: 3, thenDragTo: finishPoint)
```

As you can see this method only drags to a specific location.  But what i need is to drag it left and right continuously for that specific duration and i cannot find any method to achieve this.

PS: This is not swipeLeft and swipeRight, drag means after long press you can drag the button to left and right not just an ordinary tap.

Comment: Hey, have you found the answer? I'm trying to figure out how to do drag with the right mouse button or two fingers on the touchbar...